# C++ managing objects

Tags: c++, class, object, delete-operator

I've got a game server. It creates number of instances of `Game` and adds them (Or a pointer to them? What's better? It has 10 `ints` and 5 other pointers, 10 member functions) to the vector. After that some events happen inside of the game e. g. game_ends. At this very moment the game should be deleted from the vector... What is the best way to achieve it?

The two ways we've come to are:

1. create an observer pattern. server will be an observer and game will dispatch an event to delete it.
2. set the game to `ended` state while server constantly scans the vector and deletes that games which are in `ended` state.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Pointers or instances**

If you create a pointer using `new` you have to remember to delete it. If you are using a real instance, make sure you define a `copy constructor`, because `std::vector` copies your objects often.

You can use `boost::sharedPointer<Game>`. Do not use `std::auto_ptr<Game>` with `std::vector`

From the **implementation options** I would consider the following :

The observer pattern is elegant, but how many times will it be called? Deletion from the vector will be O(n) because you will have to find it and then `erase` it.

If you know the maximum games you will have in, say a minute, and that fits into memory, you can just have a thread which iterates through the vector every minute and deletes any `ended` games.

If memory is critical, you have to use the observer pattern. If you have lots of games, and an unique identifier for each game, you can consider `std::map` instead of `vector`, and then use the observer pattern to delete from the map which will be `O(log(n))`

Answer (score 2):

The nature of your application aside, if you add objects to your vector by value rather than pointer, once they are deleted from the vector, you will not have to worry about deleting them yourself. If you have to create the objects dynamically and add them to your vector as pointers you will be responsible for their deletion.

Comment: Unless it's a vector of smart pointers. Which would be sensible.

Comment: Yes I believe that boost also has a vector type that takes pointers and automatically frees memory when they are erased - im looking for a link to that as I type

Answer (score 2):

An object shouldn't really determine *its own* lifetime. You should probably have some sort of managing context which owns the *container* and which can decide when an object needs to go. The actual `Game` elements may somehow notify the manager that they're done, but they shouldn't delete themselves, or remove themselves from a collection.

Comment: I would disagree on objects managing their own lifetime. For some tasks (async dispatch, spawning another program) it's completely acceptable for an object to destroy itself when it is done.

Answer (score 1):

> Create an object or a pointer to object game?

Is the game object large? Does it contain other pointers or pointers to files, sockets or other such things?

If the answer to either of those is yes, then you should new the game object, and store a pointer to it.

> Should you use observer or constantly scan?

To answer this better I would need to know more about your program. Currently it seems like a design decision you are better fit to make. If you scan constantly you will need to spin a thread. This might not be what you want.

I personally would use an observer pattern.

Comment: It has 10 ints and 5 other pointers, 10 member functions and stores a 2 socket descriptors

Comment: @Kolyunya If your object owns sockets, then I don't think you can safely copy it into a another object in side a vector. New it and store a pointer. See this about copying sockets: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5425666/passing-around-boostasioiptcpsocket

Comment: But socket file descriptor is just an integer. Smth like `5` or `10`. What's the problem, if I store this integer into the instance and push the instance to the vector? It's just an integer.

Comment: @Kolyunya: if the object owns the socket descriptor it will want to close it when it's destroyed, so, if you make copies, you'll try to close twice the same sockets.

Comment: No, no, no... Sockets are managed by the other class... `game` stores socket descriptor only to send data to them