# boost::asio, Creating a std::vector <boost::asio::ip::tcp::iostream>?

Tags: c++, boost

I need to extend an `boost::asio::ip::tcp::iostream` application to be able to connect to multiple clients. For this, i am trying to create a:

`std::vector<boost::asio::ip::tcp::iostream>`

and add iostreams, like this:

```
std::vector<boost::asio::ip::tcp::iostream> streams;

        boost::asio::io_service ios;
        boost::asio::ip::tcp::endpoint endpoint
            = boost::asio::ip::tcp::endpoint(boost::asio::ip::tcp::v4(), 4444);
        boost::asio::ip::tcp::acceptor acceptor(ios, endpoint);
        boost::asio::ip::tcp::iostream stream;

        acceptor.accept(*stream.rdbuf());

        streams.emplace_back(std::move(stream)); // gives error
```

the above code gives me an `Attempted to reference a deleted function` error.

I have tried `push_back`, and `emplace_back` as well. Is there a way to use a `std::vector<boost::asio::ip::tcp::iostream>`?

Comment: are you compiling with --std=c++11 or higher? Which version of boost?

Comment: Boost 1.64, static libs, Windows 10, visual studio 2017. Thank you

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Cannot use movable objects with Boost.Asio](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17908369/cannot-use-movable-objects-with-boost-asio)

Comment: Upgrade your boost version because `basic_socket_iostream` can be moved since 1.66 version, see reference.

Comment: Thank you! That has indeed solved it.